# Python logging module does not send email

Tags: logging, python-3.x, smtp

I'm trying to log my web applications errors/exceptions to file and to email. Logging to file works, yet email is not sent. Python version is 3.4.

Code:

```
# Filename: my_app/log.py

import logging
import logging.handlers
from . import config

LOG_FILENAME = '{}/logs/app.log'.format(config.module_path)

# Logger and it's output level
app_logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')
app_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# File handler
file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=50000, backupCount=2)

#  Add smtp handler
email_info = {
    "mailhost": '{}:{}'.format(config.email["host"], config.email["port"]),
    "fromaddr": ['robot@example.com'],
    "toaddrs": ['egis@example.com'],
    "subject": 'Kraken escaped!',
    "credentials": (config.email["username"], config.email["passwd"]),
    "secure": (),
}
smtp_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(**email_info)

formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '<%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s> %(message)s')

file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
smtp_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

app_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
app_logger.addHandler(smtp_handler)






# Filename: my_app/delivery/controllers.py

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# ... and when exceptions occurs I do following (in except statement)

logger.exception(exc)

# As I've said - it gets logged to a file, but email is not sent (fails silently?).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `"secure": None` instead of `"secure": ()`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong, yes, I've tried that. Also tried without `secure`. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...I should read documentation more carefully. It states that if port is not 'default' then `mailhost` argument should be a `(hostname, port)` tuple and not 'hostname:port' string.

Fix is following:

```
email_info = {
    "mailhost": (config.email["host"], config.email["port"]),
    #....
}
```